# Table doesn't exist After Creating a Temp Table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, temp-tables

Hi  I am creating a temp table and insert a record using

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table_extension_details (
                  `Id` int NOT NULL,
                  `model_code` varchar(10),
                  `model_description` varchar(50),
                  `eta` varchar(100),
                  `options` varchar(100),
                  `order_numbers` varchar(200),
                  PRIMARY KEY(Id)
                );


 INSERT INTO temp_table_extension_details (model_code,model_description,eta,options,order_numbers) 
    VALUES('ABCD','description','eta','abc,bcd,def','123,234,345,456');
```

I tried this using PHPMyadmin and it says `# 1 row affected.`

but when i try to select the data using

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table_extension_details
```

It gives me an error and says

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table_extension_details 
 LIMIT 0, 25 
MySQL said: Documentation

#1146 - Table 'trans.temp_table_extension_details' doesn't exist .
```

Is there any reson for this , i want to create a temp table and insert some data , later i will select all the data from it and delete the temp table .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: commit ? flush ? etc

Comment: Each query with PhpMyAdmin is a new database connection. Variables and temporary tables don't persist between them.

Comment: So the same would happen if you would try to only create the table in the first request and input something in a second request. so to select something from it, you need to execute all three statement in each request :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Temporary tables only exist during the connection. If you create it with one query and then do a separate query on a new connection it is already gone.

Comment: Awesome. so HOW do you do that?

Comment: You would have to create a real table in mysql and manage the dropping/creating at your application level.

Answer (score 0):

As Christian wrote, temporary tables only exist during the connection.
Since you are using phpMyAdmin you can do what you want that is CREATE a temporary table, work with it, and delete the table but you have to do it in one instruction with multiple statements separated by a semicolon (;)
So in phpMyAdmin, in SQL TAB, after your CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE instruction add (;) then SELECT * FROM alias or any query then (;) and so on and finally click on Go button.
All the statements will be executed without losing the connection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).