# Why is Temporary Table Empty?

Tags: mysql, select, temp-tables, prepend

I have created a query

```
SELECT prodID, m.memberID, status, dues, checkNo, payDate 
FROM memberDues m 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT memberID, MAX(payDate) 
            AS mxPayDate FROM memberDues 
            GROUP BY memberID ) mp 
            ON m.memberID = mp.memberID 
AND payDate = mxPayDate
```

This yields the the output I'm looking for - in this case selecting only the most recent transaction for each member. The problem I have is trying to put that output into a temporary table. My code is then modified like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempMemberDues  AS (
SELECT prodID, m.memberID, status, dues, checkNo, payDate 
FROM memberDues m 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT memberID, MAX(payDate) 
            AS mxPayDate FROM memberDues 
            GROUP BY memberID ) mp 
            ON m.memberID = mp.memberID 
AND payDate = mxPayDate
)
```

When I run this query, I get the response

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

Why is my temporary table empty if the CREATE TEMPORARYT TABLE statement is prepended to a statement that produced results?

Comment: Did you actually try doing a `SELECT *` from that temporary table?  I don't see any reason why this would be happening unless the data really be there, or the data were deleted.

Comment: At your suggestion I tried a `SELECT *` and got the same zero response. When I remove "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempMemberDues  AS" and run the query I get output. If I run a query on tempMemberDues the response is table doesn't exist.

Comment: Temporary tables only exist during a given connection, q.v. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444335/table-doesnt-exist-after-creating-a-temp-table).

Comment: That was it. Didn't realize limitation with phpmyadmin. Plugged the query into my code and it works fine.