# Tempory Table doesn't exist error

Tags: mysql, node.js, temp-tables

I have created a temporary table in mysql using node js express

```
var table_name = "table"+(+new Date());
var query = "create temporary table "+table_name+" "+select_query
```

The when I run this code I get result in console

```
result of creating temp table OkPacket {
  fieldCount: 0,
  affectedRows: 1640,
  insertId: 0,
  serverStatus: 34,
  warningCount: 0,
  message: ')Records: 1640  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0',
  protocol41: true,
  changedRows: 0 }
```

But when I try to select data from this table mysql gives error that table doesn't exist.

I am not able to figure out what is the reason behind this error.

Please help in finding solution of this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for long time I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31444335/table-doesnt-exist-after-creating-a-temp-table)

Temporary tables only exist during the connection. If you create it with one query and then do a separate query on a new connection it is already gone.